# cursor position reset on frontend text editor code highlighting

Tags: javascript, highlight, text-editor

DOM

```html
<pre id="input" contenteditable="true"></pre>
```

JS

```js
const hlSelection = window.getSelection();
const hlRange = document.createRange();
function hl(value = input.innerText) {
  const cursorExist = hlSelection.anchorNode instanceof Node;
  if (cursorExist) {
    // save cursor pos
    hlRange.setStart(hlSelection.anchorNode, hlSelection.anchorOffset);
    hlRange.setEnd(hlSelection.focusNode, hlSelection.focusOffset);
  }
  input.innerHTML = hljs.highlight(value, {
    language: "markdown",
  }).value;
  if (cursorExist) {
    // load cursor pos
    hlSelection.removeAllRanges();
    hlSelection.addRange(hlRange);
  }
}
```

This won't work. because after overwriting `input.innerHTML`, `hlSelection.anchorNode` and `hlSelection.focusNode` will be replaced by other nodes and make `hlRange` meaningless. And methods like using result of this expression:

```js
Array.from(hlRange.startContainer.parentElement.childNodes)
  .indexOf(hlRange.startContainer)
```

also won't work because highlighting might change Node count.

How can I locate new nodes?